# jQuery slider problems: two buttons are getting confused about the state

Tags: jquery, toggle, reset

I have built a slider that has two possible buttons: one to `.toggle`, this one is always visible, and then the `.click` one which is only visable when the slide is open so i wanted it to only close. the problem is when you open with the .toggle and close with the `.click` then try to re-open with the original `.toggle` button. it needs 2 clicks of the mouse at that point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".profile_slide_btn").toggle(

     function(){
       $("#sliding_header").animate({ 
         top: "0px"
       }, 300 );
     }, 

     function(){
      $("#sliding_header").animate({ 
         top: "-600px"
       }, 300 );
  });

 $(".profile_slide_btn2").click(

     function(){
       $("#sliding_header").animate({ 
         top: "-600px"
       }, 300 );
     });
  });

</script>
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the toggle runs one function & then the other, so because you closed with the `.click`, but the toggle doesn't know that, when you click the `.toggle` again, it tries to close first.

Might have to change your logic to manually do the toggle instead of relying on the `.toggle` function.

**Edit**: So something like this (note this is untested & you may have issues where clicking things during the animation cause weirdness):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".profile_slide_btn").click(
            function(){
                if ($("#sliding_header").css("top") == "0px") {
                    hideHeader();
                } else {
                    showHeader();
                }
            });

        $(".profile_slide_btn2").click(hideHeader);

        function showHeader() {
            $("#sliding_header").animate({ top: "0px" }, 300 );
        }

        function hideHeader() {
            $("#sliding_header").animate({ top: "-600px" }, 300 );
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: That sounds right to me, I am not very versed in my syntax. How would you write that?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the .toggle doesn't know the slider has been closed.

1. Open with toogle : 0px
2. Close with click: -600px
3. Toggle still thinks you intend to close, so: -600px again

Use an if to know when the slider's top property is -600px and when 0, that way you know when to close and when to open.

Comment: Do you have possibly a resource about using an 'if', i am a little green still.